# replace the cloudwatch request id with a custom unique id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to send an unique id to my cloudwatch event.
The below image shows the request id. This unique id has to be changed.

[image]

Below is the serverless.yml code for my lambda function.
I tried to add an input (InputTransformers) but it didn't do much.
What can i do here???

```
functions:
  stream-function:
    handler: src/stream-handler/stream.handler
    memorySize: 1024 #in MB, also control CPU throughput
    timeout: 31 #in seconds, match with downstream to avoid concurrent request
    events:
      - stream:
          type: kinesis
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [HagoStream, Arn]
          batchSize: 1
          parallelizationFactor: 2
          Id: "my cloud watch rule name"
          InputTransformer: {
               InputTemplate: '{"uniqueId": "96c80428-14fe-c8d0-f6e3-639384992391"}',
                InputPathsMap: {
                  id: '$.uniqueId'
                }
            }
          maximumRetryAttempts: 2
          destinations:
            onFailure:
              arn:
                Fn::GetAtt: [HagoFailedQueue, Arn]
              type: sqs

    environment:
      DLQ_URL:
        Ref: HagoDlqQueue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is AWS assigned [unique ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html) for your lambda function invocation. You **can't change** it.

> RequestId – The unique request ID for the invocation.

Instead, in your function code, you can generate some extra ID that you output in CloudWatch Logs alongside with other data of yours.

Comment: Noted. Ok i want to send an extra Unique ID to my logs. What is the best way to do it??

Comment: @grooot Its use case specfic. In python, just do `print(f"MyRequestId: {id-that-you-somehow-generated-based-on-your-application-needs}")`.

Comment: @grooot How did it go? Did you manage to generate the ID?